# Return Results on Right Outer Join on empty table with where condtion

Tags: t-sql, conditional-statements, outer-join

So I'm trying to return 12 months of data from `billing_monthly_verizon_charges_detail_archive`, and I can't find a way to make to return 0s when there is no data without removing the condition `verizon.ITEM_DESCRIPTION <> 'Payment Received'`. I get why it's not returning any data, but how can I make it return 0 for each of the months `invoice_date table` with the conditional - which is needed for when there is data.

```
SELECT 'H. Verizon' AS category, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), id.INVOICE_DATE, 111) AS invoice_date, ISNULL(SUM(verizon.COST), 0.00) AS total_charges
FROM BILLING_MONTHLY_VERIZON_CHARGES_DETAIL_ARCHIVE AS verizon 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
INVOICE_DATES AS id ON verizon.BILL_CYCLE_DATE = id.INVOICE_DATE
WHERE(id.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN @BillingMonthMinus13 AND @BillingMonth) AND (verizon.ITEM_DESCRIPTION <> 'Payment Received')
GROUP BY id.INVOICE_DATE
```

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 0):

```
COALESCE(verizon.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,'') <> 'Payment Received'
```

Answer (score 0):

consider:

```
SELECT  
    'H. Verizon' AS category, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), INVOICE_DATE,111) AS invoice_date, 
    ISNULL(SUM(COST), 0.00) AS total_charges
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        INVOICE_DATE
    FROM
        INVOICE_DATES 
    WHERE
        INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN @BillingMonthMinus13 AND @BillingMonth ) id    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        BILL_CYCLE_DATE, 
        COST
    FROM
        BILLING_MONTHLY_VERIZON_CHARGES_DETAIL_ARCHIVE
    WHERE
        ITEM_DESCRIPTION <> 'Payment Received'  ) verizon   ON 
    BILL_CYCLE_DATE = INVOICE_DATE
GROUP BY 
    INVOICE_DATE
```